# How to flatten (or explode) the data along with row in a Dataframe, based on column data?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

Data frame should explode based on SPC column. Below is example

My Input DataFrame.

```
ID Name Level SPC Rating salry                                                     
23 sam     3  HBS  3.5    4000                
43 Nair 4     KSTk    4   5000           
56 Rom  5     MNC    3    3000
```

My output should be:

```
ID Name level SPC Rating Salary                                                    
23 sam   3    H    3.5    4000    
23 sam   3    B    3.5    4000        
23 sam   3    S    3.5    4000      
43 Nair  4    K    4      5000      
43 Nair  4    S    4      5000      
43 Nair  4    T    4      5000     
43 Nair  4    k    4      5000
```

How can I resolve this problem in Scala or Java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a dataframe/dataset as

```
+---+----+-----+----+------+------+
|ID |Name|Level|SPC |Rating|salary|
+---+----+-----+----+------+------+
|23 |sam |3    |HBS |3.5   |4000  |
|43 |Nair|4    |KSTk|4.0   |5000  |
|56 |Rom |5    |MNC |3.0   |3000  |
+---+----+-----+----+------+------+
```

then you can write a `udf` function to convert the `SPC` column string values to array of each characters as string and then use `explode` function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def flattenStringUdf = udf((spc: String) => spc.toList.map(_.toString))

df.withColumn("SPC", explode(flattenStringUdf(col("SPC")))).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+----+-----+---+------+------+
|ID |Name|Level|SPC|Rating|salary|
+---+----+-----+---+------+------+
|23 |sam |3    |H  |3.5   |4000  |
|23 |sam |3    |B  |3.5   |4000  |
|23 |sam |3    |S  |3.5   |4000  |
|43 |Nair|4    |K  |4.0   |5000  |
|43 |Nair|4    |S  |4.0   |5000  |
|43 |Nair|4    |T  |4.0   |5000  |
|43 |Nair|4    |k  |4.0   |5000  |
|56 |Rom |5    |M  |3.0   |3000  |
|56 |Rom |5    |N  |3.0   |3000  |
|56 |Rom |5    |C  |3.0   |3000  |
+---+----+-----+---+------+------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: It is working for me.Thank you very much ramesh Maharajan.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [flatMap](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html) method.

Example (haven't checked if this compiles):

```
val output = input.flatMap(row =>
    row.SPC.toList.map(ch =>
        new MyRow(row.ID, row.Name, row.level, ch, row.Rating, row.Salaray))
```